# Failed to Parse JSON Array Inside JSON Array

Tags: android, json

I have JSON Response like this :

```
{
  "ResponseCode": "000",
  "ResponseDescription": "Successful",
  "ResponseData": [
    [
      "RequestID",
      "ProviderAuditID",
      "RequestTime",
      "Product",
      "ProductCode",
      "Currency",
      "Value",
      "ValueRes",
      "ValuePro",
      "TransactionResponseCode",
      "TransactionResponseDescription"
    ],
    [
      "23",
      null,
      "2013-07-22 07:09:06",
      "Test Product",
      "098",
      "India",
      "456.000000",
      "456.000000",
      "456.000000",
      null,
      null
    ],   
  ]
}
```

Now i want to parse this value and set it into the list view so
can anyone help me out how to achieve this ???

**EDIT ::**

I have the multiple values in parsing,this is just an example ...

Comment: you might need to use multiple foreach loops

Comment: this is very bad approach to use JSON.

Comment: What do you want to do with it ? Instanciate a class with the same attributes ? Juste displaying the data?

Comment: You should use like `"ResponseData": {
      "RequestID" : 23,
      "ProviderAuditID" : "id",
...
}`

Comment: @PankajKumar yes,i know but i have to done parsing this ways only.... no choice for me ,can u plz help me to achieve this ? :(

Comment: can you share your code which you are using

Comment: Sorry, I noted this below in the answer I upvoted. There is a trailing comma on the third last line that kills this.

Comment: @Enrichman m trying..... plz allow me some more time ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrapper object with an array in one of the fields. That field contains a List of String.

Parse your json into a JSONObject, then you can simply get your JSONArray and get the list inside it.

This should work:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("ResponseData");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray arrValues = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);
    // do what you have to do with the values
    for (int i = 0; i < arrValues.length(); i++) {
        String value = (String) arrValues.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It May Work But I Check The AndroidLearner's JSON In http://jsonlint.com/ Its Wrong

Comment: It's wrong for the trailing comma, probably because he copied it wrong.

Comment: @Enrichman `List<String> myList = (List<String>) jsonArray.get(i);` this line shows me the `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray`.

Comment: Hm... edited! Try this one. : )

Comment: @Enrichman I got all the values,but how can i store this, because i want to display this thing in list view also....

Comment: Ok, but that's another problem. :)
If you solved THIS question you should accept the answer. Then if you have further problems you should open another one. Hint: look on how implement an ArrayAdapter. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check your json data.
using the following website -http://jsonlint.com/

Your json is not valid.

Comment: I have already checked the JSON in JSONLINT,Its 100 % vaild ..

Comment: Please check i am geting error in your json string.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. In particular, the trailing comma on the third last line is invalid.

Comment: @dpjanes Its a typo mistake.plz note my edit in my question where i have mentioned that there will be multiple records,this is just an example.so at the time of copying i forget to remove the comma..